# Why are unhandled exceptions thrown in win32 timer callbacks not treated as unhandled exceptions by the debugger?

Tags: c++, winapi, exception

I've been tracking down a really insidious bug at work. The event that seems to cause the very strange behavior I've been tracking down appears to be an exception being thrown while processing a timer callback. The exception is NOT handled by any of my code, therefore I would expect the debugger to be notified of the unhandled exception and alert me with a nice obnoxous pop-up. No, instead the "first chance" exception message traces out to the debugger and everything silently moves on.

I've written up the following program that demonstrates this issue:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

class FooExcept
{
};

VOID CALLBACK Timer(HWND hwnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    UINT_PTR idEvent,
    DWORD dwTime)
{
    printf("Here\n");
    throw FooExcept();
    printf("Also Here\n");
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SetTimer(0, 0, 1000, Timer);

    int bRet;
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG msg;
    // Standard Win32 message pump
    while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) != 0)
    { 
        if (bRet == -1)
        {
            // handle the error and possibly exit
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg); 
            DispatchMessage(&msg); 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program to the Visual Studio Output window is this repeated:

```
First-chance exception at 0x76dbb9bc in TimerTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: FooExcept at memory location 0x0034f743..
```

Of course my project is MUCH more complicated and is printing out a lot of TRACE information to the debugger. Its easy for first-chance exception to get lost in the output.

HOWEVER

That's not my concern. This is clearly an exception Im not handling. Is Windows surreptitiously deciding to handle this for me? Why? If not, why isn't it giving me a blatant pop-up alerting me of the unhandled exception? Such a pop-up could have saved me days of debugging.

This behavior seems consistent between XP/VS 2008 and Win7/VS 2010.

Comment: sounds eerily related:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001776/issue-with-exceptions-being-caught-by-win32-message-dispatcher

Comment: also related over at MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/c1e34bd0-8ea4-4869-bb20-4e4d0ed586fe

Comment: http://bugswar.blogspot.com/2010/07/why-its-not-crashing.html

Comment: @HansPassant the worst part is that sometimes it seems [Destructors aren't being called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903811/why-arent-my-destructors-called-when-throwing-from-a-win32-timer-callback)

Comment: Well sure, they are only called when an exception is caught by a C++ try block.  Cold hard fact is that there's no modern message loop left that doesn't catch them all.  See MFC's usage of AfxProcessWndProcException() for example.  Same recipe in Winforms and WPF.  Writing user32 code is not for mortals anymore, hasn't been for a while, use a class library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been been fixed, to some degree (see below), in Windows 7 SP1.

In article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976038 you will find mention of a bugfix and explanation how to use it to disable this behaviour. You have to either:

- set process options in the registry or
- call function `SetProcessUserModeExceptionPolicy` exported by `kernel32.dll`

I have verified in [Updates in Win7 and WS08R2 SP1.xls](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=269) that this bugfix is indeed included in Windows 7 Service Pack 1, so all you have to do is to enable it (assuming you are lucky enough to have Windows 7 SP1 already installed).

As for explanation *why this has been done*, well we can just guess some ill-advised attempt to prevent legacy application from crashing in the name of *backwards compatibility*.

Comment: PS (not really part of answer) I found this, large and complete, blog post on the subject http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/

Comment: Unbelievable how Microsoft could let this pass. Shows a lot how many people really develop for and under 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

For the message itself I don't know, but for the error path, this is because the callback comes from the OS. Then the exception returns to the OS and not to your program or to your debugger. It's same on Linux. In this case you can get a strange error. The solution to resolve that is to use a custom interface or an error callback to return the error to your program caller. The same problem also comes in multithreaded apps where the thread is created by the OS and the exceptions are also returned to the OS and not to your program. The OS knows nothing about your exception handlers.